# Don't show hidden applications when using Command-Tab

Tags: macos

I'm wondering if there's a way to not show hidden applications in the list of running apps when using Command-Tab ?

LiteSwitch (http://www.proteron.com/) sort of does what I want, except it grays out hidden applications, but I want them to not appear at all.

I use hidden applications as a sort of 'I'll get to later, or don't bother me now' method, so it would be great if Command-Tab could honor that (the same was Expose does).

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds pretty sneaky....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Okay, actually looks like this is the ticket: Switché

You can also assign applications to an ignore list so that certain ones will never show up in the task switcher.

Screenshots here:

[image]

### Get it

Review with more screenshots here:

http://mac.appstorm.net/reviews/utilities/switche-application-switching-on-steroids/

Download:
http://kapeli.com/switche/

And one more screenshot with the "ignore applications" feature:

[image]

Comment: seems to do the trick, thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

Switché isn't available any more. You can hide *any* app by editing its `Info.plist` file. Here's how:

1. Right click on the app, and hit **"Show Package Contents"**
2. In the 'Contents' folder, open **"Info.plist" using a text editor**
3. Paste the following **under the <dict> line**:

   ```
   <key>NSUIElement</key>
   <string>1</string>
   ```

This will hide any app from the finder. If the app updates itself, you'll need to redo these steps.

I've added this to Skype, 1Password and Finder and they all run perfectly, but don't appear in the command-tab menu. In combination with [Alfred App](http://www.alfredapp.com/) it works so well – hit alt-space and you can launch any app hidden from the app switcher back to its original state!

Comment: Oh, this doesn't just hide hidden apps – it always hides them, regardless of the app state.

Comment: It also removes the menu bar. If the application is signed, editing the Info.plist breaks the code signature, so the application is not allowed to access keychains automatically. Also since 10.8 some applications like TextEdit and Mail have crashed on launch if their Info.plist has been modified.

Comment: Doesn't work in 10.11.4 for app: MAMP  :(