# OSX: Hide applications or minimized programs from Command + Tab quick switch menu

Tags: macos

Is it possible to hide applications or minimized applications from the Command + Tab quick switch menu? I don't want to hide them from the dock however, as I need to get back to them some how.

Comment: Related questions: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99892, http://superuser.com/questions/230060, http://superuser.com/questions/507972.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the application using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. that won't hide it from dock.

However minimizing the application can be done 2 ways.

- Minimize to the application icon:

> Dock preferences >> Minimize window into application icon [check it]

- Minimize in the application running apps area:

> Dock preferences >> Minimize window into application icon [un-check it]